# Sideload Factory OS via ADB

Tags: adb, side-loading, nexus-6, factory-image

I have a nexus 6 which failed when updating to 6.0.1. I can no longer boot into the Operating System as the /system partition is corrupt. I ran a factory reset - but this didn't fix the problem because factory reset only clears out the /cache and /data partitions.

Since I am able to get into the bootloader and android recovery I was wondering if it is possible to reinstall the OS via ADB. I've searched around it it looks like ADB can only be used for installing updates/programs while fastboot can flash the /system partition with a factory image. I'm unable to use fastboot because the phone is not rooted. So, is there any way to restore the factory image of the OS via ADB on a non-rooted phone?

Comment: You don't have to bother about having phone being rooted since you would have all the rights necessary to flash a partition when booted into fastboot (bootloader) mode. Now, download the appropriate factory image from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#shamu), boot into fastboot mode and begin flashing the various files. I'm wondering whether you had OEM unlock setting enabled or not? That may pose a problem. BTW, what actually failed during OTA update to 6.0.1 (not 6.1.1)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use fastboot (or the flash-all script) to flash the files because the phone doesn't have OEM unlock enabled. Running `adb sideload image-shamu-mob30i.zip` doesn't work, saying that the footer is wrong and signature verification failed (even though the MD5 checksum checks out).